# Session is getting broken on trying to switch to new popup window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium-java 3.9, IE 11 browser to develop selenium scripts on our client application.

When I am clicking on link to open a new popup window, session is getting broken and login page is appearing in the popup window page. How can I resolve this issue.

The same scenario is working well in chrome and IE 8 and IE 9 versions. But due to browser compatibility issues, I am forced to use IE 11.

Comment: What do you mean with 'session is getting broken' ? Dou you need to open the login page in same window (new tab)? Or just switching driver to the new window? Pls always try to describe your issue as detailed as possible with html source code, your code and what is exactly the issue. Optionaly add screenshots.

Comment: usually, we login into our client application with specific login credentials. In one particular scenario when I click on a link in the main page, a new page will get displayed as a popup window.But In the popup window expected page is not getting displayed. instead it is again displaying login page asking for login credentials. Thats the problem. As I am working for a client, I am not supposed to post the screenshots of the application.

Comment: Can ba a bug in the application itself. Can you proceed the scenario manualy?

Comment: Yes. I can proceed the scenario manually. Its working.

Comment: Is it the page who is asking for credetials? Or some authorization dialog? What I mean what session is beeing lost? Client - application or client - proxy?

Answer (score 0):

While executing the automation script, after login , need to click on certain button which opens the login page again instead of the expected page.
While doing manually, after clicking on the same button it opens the required page.
This happens only in IE11 not in chrome.
As the recommended browser is IE, need to proceed with this.
What can be the reason and its solution.